# C pointer to array as argument of func

Tags: c

I saw in internet that pointer to array and pointer to first element of array are the same things. But in CooCox next call an error:

```
//Get Arr
uint8_t TestDataArr[10];
//Func get pointer to arr
void InitData (TestPacks *Data)
{
//Some code
}
//This call error
InitData(&TestDataArr)
//But this is norm
InitData(&TestDataArr[0])
```

Why did it happen?

Comment: Because they are not the same thing... A pointer to an array has a different type than a pointer to an arrays first element, even if the addresses coincide.

Comment: No they are not the same thing. Don't believe everything you find on the internets.

Comment: Read this for a more elaborate explanation (not sure if it's a proper dup) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays

Comment: Remove `&` in first function call and it would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InitData(&TestDataArr)
```

is not equal to

```
InitData(&TestDataArr[0])
```

cause `TestDataArr[0]` is equal to `*TestDataArr` and then `InitData(&TestDataArr[0])` equal to `InitData(&*TestDataArr)` or `InitData(TestDataArr)`.
You can see, that

```
InitData(&TestDataArr)
```

is the address of `TestDataArr` and

```
InitData(TestDataArr)
```

just the array.
That are also different types!

Comment: They *are* the same address, only different types.

Comment: sorry, i mistaked. func init as 'void InitData (uint8_t*Data)'. Types are equal

Comment: No, they do not point to the same memory. `&TestDataArr` is the pointer, which points to the  `TestDataArr`-variable -- (type is `uint8_t**`/`uint8_t[10]*`). So it points to the pointer that points to the data. `TestDataArr` is pointing to the data directly.

Comment: For a given  `uint8_t TestDataArr[10];` doing `&TestDataArr` results in a `uint8_t(*)[10]`. It does ***not*** result in a `uint8_t**`.

Comment: Print them. What do you get? "it points to the pointer that points to the data" Why do you think such a pointer exists anywhere in memory?